# Load Image from IP camera and show it in PictureBox1

Tags: c#, url

I'm trying to make viewer for IP camera only. No Big deal but I came to a problem where Image is opened and loaded into `picturebox1` but it wont refresh, no matter if I set timer in `timer1` to 500 (ms)

Code :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://IPofIPCamera/now.jpg";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic",
            new NetworkCredential("SomeUser", "SomePass"));
        webClient.Credentials = myCache;
        MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(url));
        pictureBox1.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imgStream);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Update();
    }
}
```

With this code `PictureBox1` is image loaded from url but is not refreshed.
What Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: does `pictureBox1.Update()` trigger the download again? I strongly doubt that, and believe you should extract a method for downloading and setting the image to `pictureBox1.Image`, which is triggered by the tick of the timer ...

Comment: I'd guess you have to execute the two last lines from `Form1_Load` in `timer1_Tick`(and extract the required local variables).

Comment: Updating `pictureBox1` is not enough. You need to re-download the image from the camera, which basically means you have to re-run the `Form1_Load()` code in `time1_Tick()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a misunderstanding of how `PictureBox.Update` works, which is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx):

> Causes the control to redraw the invalidated regions within its client area.

This means that the download is not triggered again.

To resolve your issue you should extract a method for downloading and setting the image, which will be triggered by the tick of your timer.

```
public void DownloadAndUpdatePicture()
{
  string url = "http://IPofIPCamera/now.jpg";
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
  myCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("SomeUser", "SomePass"));
  webClient.Credentials = myCache;
  MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(url));
  pictureBox1.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imgStream);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.DownloadAndUpdatePicture();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.DownloadAndUpdatePicture();
}
```